# Sharing multiple files on App Via iTunes File Sharing (Code shows 1 file)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, itunes

I'm trying to file share multiple files with iTunes file share.

Here is the current code.

Delegate.h

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // file sharing trying
    {
        NSString *fileName = @"Test.mp3";
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath])
        {
            NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
        }
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

At the moment only 1 file gets shared.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to add a bunch of files in an NSArray? then loop through it like this:

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"foo", @"bar", nil];
for (NSString *fileName in names)
{
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSError *error;
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString *documentDBFolderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

     if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:documentDBFolderPath])
     {
         NSString *resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
         [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:documentDBFolderPath error:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but none of the files shown. I thought the file names would have to be shown?